# What is the encoding of these GIFs?

Tags: encoding, gif

What is the encoding of the gifs included in the following SEC document?

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1010775/000095012310034416/0000950123-10-034416.txt

Also I wonder about the whole document, but really I just want to see the juicy pics...

Example text, too long to fully quote:

```````
<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>GRAPHIC
<SEQUENCE>2
<FILENAME>h72151fh72151z0001.gif
<DESCRIPTION>GRAPHIC
<TEXT>
begin 644 h72151fh72151z0001.gif
M1TE&.#=AT`(<`O<``````.#@X$!`0``X<$B@T"`@($"0R!@8&%!XJ`!0B"@@
M(`!8F$!@B,"XP$"8,"A8@``H8*B@H.#P^"!`:`!(>(B(B$"08)"@N#"0&&!X
MH%"8B'AX>"A0<*C`T!@X8$"0T"B(P"A(<&"0P("@N,#@Z"`X8"A0@"!(:&AP
M:`!XN!@X6"!(<)BPR.C@X&B0L,C8X&AH:$!XF!!`<"!8@"!`8*BXR&B8R(BH
MP'"HT-#0T%!84)"HP"`X6!A(<%"`H"A@B+#(V.#PX!"`N&B8V`@("$"8R)#`
MX("`B!A`8/CX^"!(>,#(V`!PL)B@H+BXN"A0>("8L.CP\&B(H("PX&B@V-C8
MV)B8F%"(L"!0>$AHD'"@V#@P.%AXF*C0Z$A(2,#0V-C@X&B8T.#HZ"A(>&"8
MR!A`6!A(>#!HD`!XP)"PP("XV'B0J+C`T%"`N+"PJ#!8@-#8X$AXL'B`>/#X
M^&"HT'BHV`!HJ``X:`!PN`!`<$!HD,C`R)C(X%!PF'"(J!A`<!`0$/#P\$AP
MD)"0D#`P,!A0@`A(>""(P.CH\+C8Z$"0:-CHZ,C0V#B0R&!@8&"8T-#@Z#A@
MB%"`L'B0L/#P^)BXR!!0@&B`H(B8L#!8B'"8L.#P\%!04'"HV)C`X,#8Z&BP
MV`!`>)BHP.#H\&"@T&"(J*"PP+C(T`@X:&"8P&"0R.#@Z$!HB#AHD!B`P%!X
MF%BHV(C`X'BXV%!PD+#`T`!PP)"HN#"0R'"0J,C0X-#@\*"8H`AXN+C`P`!@
MH*BHJ+"PN``P:%"(N'B8L&"`F`!0F*#`T+#0Z+"PL-C8X-C@Z'"PV&"`H*"P

<!-- etc --> 

</DOCUMENT>
```````

Comment: C'mon... there are lots of these questions out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [uuencoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding). If you drop the contents into a file:

```````
begin 644 h72151fh72151z0001.gif
M1TE&.#=AT`(<`O<``````.#@X$!`0``X<$B@T"`@($"0R!@8&%!XJ`!0B"@@
M(`!8F$!@B,"XP$"8,"A8@``H8*B@H.#P^"!`:`!(>(B(B$"08)"@N#"0&&!X
MH%"8B'AX>"A0<*C`T!@X8$"0T"B(P"A(<&"0P("@N,#@Z"`X8"A0@"!(:&AP
...
M^\B/):"/_]B/`EF.`4F0[TB0`)F0"IF0"'F0"^F0`AF1_S@TD?Q8D?AXD?68
MD?&XD?#8D>SXD>L8DNHXDNE8DOD(D2G9D"H)D?ZXD!1)C_/XDN9(`V40$``A
>_AI3;V9T=V%R93H@36EC<F]S;V9T($]F9FEC90`[
`
end
```````

You can use the [`uudecode`](https://ss64.com/bash/uuencode.html) utility or the [`uu`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uu.html) python module to decode it. Here's a python program to extract all of them from your example text file:

```python
import re
import sys
import uu
from io import BytesIO

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    p = re.compile(r"^begin.*\n(.*\n)+?^end$", re.M)
    for m in p.finditer(f.read()):
        uu.decode(BytesIO(bytes(m.group(0), encoding="utf-8")))
```

Result:

[image]